# Use IF in SELECT part of query

Tags: sql-server

I need to create something like this

```
SELECT x.id
   , x.name
   , x.type
   ,(
      IF x.type = 1
         (SELECT SUM(Col1) FROM TableA WHERE ... etc)
      ELSE IF x.type = 2
         (SELECT SUM(Col2) FROM TableB WHERE ... etc)
    ) AS Total
FROM TableX as x
```

So I am trying to select a different sub query according to the value of x.type

Wing

Comment: Do what? Please ask a question :)

Comment: You cannot select more than one column from sub-query'

Comment: Apologies I will edit post

Comment: If does not work INSIDE a query. You can use CASE WHEN <statement> THEN <true> ELSE <false> END instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.name,
       x.type,
       CASE
         WHEN x.type = 1 THEN (SELECT Sum(Col1)
                               FROM   TableA Where...)
         WHEN x.type = 2 THEN (SELECT Sum(Col2)
                               FROM   TableB  Where .. )
       END AS Total
FROM   TableX AS x
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`. Use your conditions of `x.type` to join the tables.

> COALESCE (Transact-SQL): Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
SELECT x.id
   , x.name
   , x.type
   , COALESCE(SUM(TableA.Column), SUM(TableB.Column)) as column_xyz
FROM TableX as x
LEFT JOIN TableA ON x.type = 1 AND ...
LEFT JOIN TableB ON x.type = 2 AND ...
```

You can also use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...` instead of `COALESCE` to define which column to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN` as the below:

```
SELECT 
    x.id, 
    x.name, 
    x.type,
    CASE 
        WHEN x.type = 1 THEN (SELECT SUM(A.Col1) FROM TableA A WHERE 1 = 1)
        WHEN x.type = 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(B.Col2) FROM TableB B WHERE 1 = 1)
        ELSE NULL END AS Total
FROM 
    TableX as x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `case expression`:

```
select t.* ,
            Case when t.type = 1 then (select sum(col1) ... TableA)
                      when t.type = 2 then (select sum(col2) ... TableB)
             End as Total
From tableX t
```

Answer (score 0):

By using variable -

```
DECLARE @SumA INT = SELECT SUM(Col1) FROM TableA WHERE ... etc
DECLARE @SumB INT = SELECT SUM(Col2) FROM TableB WHERE ... etc

SELECT x.id
   , x.name
   , x.type
   ,( CASE x.type
        WHEN 1 THEN @SumA
        WHEN 2 THEN @SumB
      END
    ) AS Total
FROM TableX as x
```

Choose the datatype for Sum variable accordingly (if Decimal).

Comment: Would the variable queries be run before the main query is run or only when they are called?

Comment: It has to be run in a single batch.